# Concat is not a function

Tags: angular, concatenation

Hello guys I'm trying to put the all comments in array to show at *ngFor but at subscribe data comes json object so it cannot be concat.

here is my code

**TS**

```
this.http.post('http://' + this.ipAdress + ':3100/api/infitineComments/:id', { "page": this.page }) 
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {


      if (...) { //error part
      }

      else {

        let d = [];
        for(let i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
          d.push(data[i])
        }//I did this part because data was  object in array type , also 
         //doesnt work

        this.comments = this.comments.concat(d);

        console.log("data: ", this.comments);
      }
    }, err => {
      console.log("err: ", err);
    });
```

Here small picture of my error, all list covers id, comment, userId...
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried with String(this.comments).concat(d)

Comment: Has `this.comments` been initialized?

Comment: @SandipPatel Convert to string to concatenate arrays? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Robby : i think it string so

Comment: @SandipPatel Say what now? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: @Robby : from above link it look like achievable

Comment: It's the issue of initialization of the `this.comments`. Make sure that you initialize it just as you have done for `d`. i.e. `let d = []`.

Comment: Thank you for all  String(this.comments).concat(d) worked! I appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 6):

Check that `this.comments` is well initialized as an array.

```
this.comments = []
```

Comment: Yes it is initialized like that

Comment: But are you sure that `this` operator is the same when you initialize comments and concat it ?
Can you show us how do you initialize it ?

Comment: I'm a bit new dont sure how could be they same,  but I initialize  comments:any=[]; above the constructor and concating in the infitiComment() function reaching with this.comments .Sorry if  I couldn't understand your question.

Comment: Log your comments variable in the infitiComment() function to check that it well initialize. 
If it's undefined then your problem is there. The `this` in the function refer to the scope fonction and not to your class

Answer (score 0):

Since from the screenshot there are an `_id`, I believe your're currently working with database.

To update the database, you should use any method specific to what database you're working on. Example: couchdb, puchdb, etc.